# Oozie Hive action on AWS - unpredictable ip sources break the job

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, oozie

I've been having a few days of unalloyed torture getting Hive jobs to run via Oozie on an AWS 5 machine cluster. The simplest job that involved the live metastore succeeds or fails unpredictably. The error messages are pretty unhelpful:

```
Hive failed, error message[Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [1]]
```

Thanks Oozie!

After a lot of fun changing just about every imaginable setting, I studied hivemetastore.log carefully (we have mySQL as the metastore) and realised that every successful request came from 172.31.40.3.  Unsuccessful requests came from 172.31.40.2,172.31.40.4 and 172.31.40.5 . The Hive console app makes requests without problems on  172.31.40.1

This is getting somewhere after nearly week of having no idea whatsover is going on. The question is now, what do I need to change to allow all requests from 172.31.40.1-5 in? Or funnel Oozie requests solely through 172.31.40.1 or 172.31.40.3, either.

Why would only 172.31.40.1 and 172.31.40.3 work?

all ideas and suggestions warmly received.

many thanks

Toby

Comment: What's in the hive-server log?

Comment: ok - hiveserver2.log - a bunch of Thrift errors caused by Nagios. hive.log - empty, hive-server2.log - empty.   What I'm really asking is how do the requests to Oozie get allocated to machines in the cluster to execute, and how are their permissions  set?

Answer (score 0):

this was so simple in the end - the Oozie client was only installed on 2 of the 5 machines in the cluster. Corresponding, of course, to the 2 IP addresses that could make successful requests to the hive metastore

Once we installed the Oozie client onto all the machines in the cluster, all the jobs were automatically accepted and ran OK

obvious when you know the answer ...